# Heroku build fail - Error R10 (Boot timeout)

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy a simple application, nothing big but I keep getting this error

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

even though Heroku finished with deployment long before 60 seconds pass. I have set process.env.PORT in my server also. I have a few apps on Heroku so I am familiar with deployment.

I make server bundle file (src/build/bundle.js) and client bundle file (src/dist/bundle.js) beforehand and push everything to Heroku. In package.json there is a start script that should just start the server.

Everything works fine locally.

I am using server side rendering and I have separated bundle, vendor and extractt css on client side. On server side I also bundle files and I use html-webpack-plugin. Don't know if any of that is connected, shouldn't be.

**prodServer.js**

```
const APP_PORT: number = conf.APP_PORT
const PORT: any = process.env.PORT || APP_PORT

const app: Express = new Express()

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'dist'), {maxAge: '1y'}))

app.use((req: Object, res: Object, next: () => void): void => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
  return next()
})

app.get('*', (req: Object, res: Object) => {
  res.render('index', {app: req.body, webpack: req.chunk})
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`
  Express server is up on port ${PORT}
  Production environment
  `)
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "QR",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Q",
  "main": "prodServer.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf ./src/dist && rm -rf ./src/build",
    "build-client": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.config.prod.js",
    "build-server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.config.server.prod.js",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./src/build/bundle.js"
  },
...
```

Comment: Hi Scott. How can port be taken, doesnt Heroku use it's own through process.env.PORT. The only other port I am mentioning in the production build is http://localhost:3001 for publicPath in my webpack bundle. **EDIT** actually I don't even use that port in production. I refrence bundle file directly in my html through script tag.

Comment: var instead of const on PORT

Comment: Thanks Scott. I tried it but still no luck.Still getting the same Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Ok. I managed to fix it. The problem was **DefinePlugin**. I had process.env.NODE_ENV: production and it was exchanging process.env.PORT inside my code so Heroku couldn’t connect.

Comment: how did you fix it ? can your elaborate